# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uri') error while c++ code vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Previously I have installed vs code,c\c++ extension packs,gcc compilers for c,c++(gnu-c,gnu-g++,gbd)for doing c language practice and I also did java on vs code .my scripts written in c and java get's executed well but when I try to run c++ code it displays an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uri')"like in the image below[image is a screen snippet after I tried to run hello world code in c++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEbGk.jpg)
I tried fix it by starting up from beginning from vs code website by clicking get started and setting up for c++ on windows by downloading mysys2 and i have followed the successive procedures but no use.what does this error mean

I tried setting up c++ on vs code from begging ,I tried restarting my computer, i also on internet for this error but I couldn't find one with reading uri in the brackets at the ending they are all either (reading file) or something else in at the end like:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file') .

Comment: Are you using `gcc` to compile? If so, change to `g++`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it is not common to store your own files in hidden directories like ".vscode". Those are usually only for an application's configuration.

Comment: The output also shows that you did not follow the VSCode MinGW instructions: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) if you followed the instructions you would have gcc-13-2 installed and not 6.3 (which is old)